# How do I set a custom image on an map annotation?

Tags: ios, skmaps

I want to set a custom image to a `SKAnnotation` but when I set the image path the markers wont appear. I set the marker image with the following code:

```
annotation.imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"64-map-test" ofType:@"png"];
annotation.imageSize = 64;
```

When I use a default image:

```
annotation.annotationType = SKAnnotationTypeGreen;
```

the markers do appear correctly.

How do I set a custom image on an map annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**png-8** file format is not supported. Using a **png-24** file works correctly.

Comment: png-24 does not work on my side. This is the image I'm using: cl.ly/image/0l0T2n1B3O07 (Photoshop generated, 64x64, 24-bit transparent PNG) SKAnnotation *annotation = [SKAnnotation annotation]; // set unique ID // set location annotation.imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"purpleAlert" ofType:@"png"]; [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation]; No luck. Nothing is displayed.

Comment: To my experience the images are not recognized this way when they are in an Assets-Catalog, they need to be added to the "normal" file structure (as they used to be before image asset catalogues)

Comment: @Conaaando On iOS there is some kind of issue that you need to set PNG Compression as NO in your bundle settings in order to work with custom images.