# Skobbler Android - How to set a custom image in an annotation on a map?

Tags: android, image, annotations, skmaps

As indicated in the title, I try to put my own image in an annotation on a map.
For this I use this code:

```
annotation.setImagePath (mImagePath);
annotation.setImageSize (4096);
annotation.setOffset (mSKScreenPoint));
```

No error but nothing appears.

Yet I followed indications of the doc:

```
"Sets the absolute path of the image file to be added as an annotation. 
The picture must be a square image and the size must be a power of 2. 
_ (32x32, 64x64, etc.)."
```

The size of my image is 64 * 64.

I had a first indication thanks to this post but nothing appears:

[How do I set a custom image on an map annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493961/how-do-i-set-a-custom-image-on-an-map-annotation)

So I converted my image to png-24 but still no result. ((

Comment: The mImagePath should be the absolute path to the image file - is that correct?

Comment: Please send an email to dev@skobbler.com and attach the icon you are trying to use & the values you have right now for mImagePath and mSKScreenPoint

Comment: with a `64px` image yo should set the image size to `64` not to `4096`.

Comment: Custom images are not working on my side too. This is the image I'm using:

http://cl.ly/image/0l0T2n1B3O07 (Photoshop generated, 64x64, 24-bit transparent PNG)

SKAnnotation *annotation = [SKAnnotation annotation];
// set unique ID
// set location
annotation.imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"purpleAlert" ofType:@"png"];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

No luck. Nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.1.0 we've added support for using images from the resources bundle & extended the examples for full path images - here's the updated prepareAnnotations code:

Update: with 2.2.0 customView support was added:

```
/**
 * Draws annotations on map
 */
private void prepareAnnotations() {

    // get the annotation object
    SKAnnotation annotation1 = new SKAnnotation();
    // set unique id used for rendering the annotation
    annotation1.setUniqueID(10);
    // set annotation location
    annotation1.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.4200, 37.7765));
    // set minimum zoom level at which the annotation should be visible
    annotation1.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    // set the annotation's type
    annotation1.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_RED);
    // render annotation on map
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);

    SKAnnotation annotation2 = new SKAnnotation();
    annotation2.setUniqueID(11);
    annotation2.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.410338, 37.769193));
    annotation2.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    annotation2.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_GREEN);
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation2, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);

    SKAnnotation annotation3 = new SKAnnotation();
    annotation3.setUniqueID(12);
    annotation3.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.430337, 37.779776));
    annotation3.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    annotation3.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_BLUE);
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation3, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);

    // add an annotation with an image file
    SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation();
    annotation.setUniqueID(13);
    annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.434516, 37.770712));
    annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(5);


    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    if (metrics.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
        // set the center point of the image - tapping on an annotation will
        // depend on
        // this value . Also the actual gps coordinates of the annotation
        // will
        // be in the center of the image.
        annotation.getOffset().setX(16);
        annotation.getOffset().setY(16);
        annotation.setImagePath(SKMaps.getInstance().getMapInitSettings().getMapResourcesPath()
                + "/.Common/poi_marker.png");
        // set the size of the image in pixels
        annotation.setImageSize(32);
    } else {
        // set the center point of the image - tapping on an annotation will
        // depend on
        // this value . Also the actual gps coordinates of the annotation
        // will
        // be in the center of the image.
        annotation.getOffset().setX(32);
        annotation.getOffset().setY(32);
        annotation.setImagePath(SKMaps.getInstance().getMapInitSettings().getMapResourcesPath()
                + "/.Common/poi_marker_retina.png");
        // set the size of the image in pixels
        annotation.setImageSize(64);

    }
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);


    // add an annotation with a drawable resource
    SKAnnotation annotationDrawable = new SKAnnotation();
    annotationDrawable.setUniqueID(14);
    annotationDrawable.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.437182, 37.777079));
    annotationDrawable.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    // set the center point of the image - tapping on an annotation will
    // depend on
    // this value . Also the actual gps coordinates of the annotation will
    // be in the center of the image.
    annotationDrawable.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(64, 64));
    SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
    annotationView.setDrawableResourceId(R.drawable.icon_map_popup_navigate);
    // set the width and height of the image in pixels (they have to be
    // powers of 2)
    annotationView.setWidth(128);
    annotationView.setHeight(128);
    annotationDrawable.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotationDrawable, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);


    // // add an annotation with a view
    SKAnnotation annotationFromView = new SKAnnotation();
    annotationFromView.setUniqueID(15);
    annotationFromView.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.423573, 37.761349));
    annotationFromView.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
    annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();

    // set view object to be displayed as annotation
    annotationView.setView(customView);
    annotationFromView.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotationFromView, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);


    selectedAnnotation = annotation1;
    // set map zoom level
    mapView.setZoom(13);
    // center map on a position
    mapView.centerMapOnPosition(new SKCoordinate(-122.4200, 37.7765));
}
```

Comment: Could you please give me an example on showing a cutom view with SKAnnotationView class.

Comment: I've updated the snippet (as a reference, it's the same code from the demo project, the MapActivity class)

Answer (score 0):

If your image is 64*64 you should set the image size as 64.

```
annotation.setImageSize(64);
```