# Custom Annotation in Skobbler map

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

I am using `Skobbler SDK VERSION 2.5.1`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304249/skobbler-android-how-to-set-a-custom-image-in-an-annotation-on-a-map). But, there are few method cannot be resolved.

- `SKAnnotation annotationDrawable = new SKAnnotation();`
- `setHeight()`
- `setWidth()`
- `setDrawableResourceId()`

I am using this for default `SKAnnotationType`.

```
private void addAnnotation(Place place) {
    if (mapView != null) {
        CustomSKAnnotation skAnnotation = new CustomSKAnnotation(new Random().nextInt(), place.getName());
        skAnnotation.setAnnotationType(SKAnnotation.SK_ANNOTATION_TYPE_BLUE);
        skAnnotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(place.getLongitude(), place.getLatitude()));
        mapView.addAnnotation(skAnnotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_PIN_DROP);
    }
}
```

I want to add my custom image as a annotation icon.
What can be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
        // add an annotation with a view
        SKAnnotation annotationFromView = new SKAnnotation(11);
        annotationFromView.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(-122.423573, 37.761349));
        annotationFromView.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
        SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
        customView =(RelativeLayout) ((LayoutInflater)
        getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                   R.layout.layout_custom_view, null, false);
        //If width and height of the view  are not power of 2 
        //the actual size of the image will be the next power of 2 of     
        //max(width,height).
        annotationView.setView(customView);
        annotationFromView.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotationFromView, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
```

<—--- layout_custom_view.xml ---—>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_searchcenter_favorite" />

</RelativeLayout>
```